# WCF Service hosted on shared host

Tags: .net, wcf, shared-hosting, assembly-loading

I developed a WCF using .NET 3.5 service to import some data to internet.

Locally all is working fine using IIS Express. When I deploy the service to shared host and point my browser to the service address I got the following exception:

> > Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My enviroment is configured to use .NET 3.5 with 32 bit compatibility.

The stack trace shows:

`[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +11655726
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +194
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, Boolean flowContext) +176
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +275
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +68
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75`

Any clues on how to solve that one?

Comment: I gave up on WCF and developed a plain old webservice to import my data. Too many issues to deploy WCF.

Answer (score 2):

"My enviroment is configured to use .NET 3.5 with 32 bit compatibility."

You sure about that? Looks a lot like your local system is using .net 4.0 and your host is only 3.5.

Comment: No, it's using .net 3.5 locally.

Comment: Check the Reference to System on your Reference list (Solution Explorer). I would bet it doesn't say 3.5

Comment: I look in all assemblies, and none of all have 4.0.0.0 version especified.

Comment: I figured it out. It was a bad configuration at my host provider. I kicked it out since then.

Answer (score 0):

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0

explicitly states that you references .NET 4.0

Comment: I made a text search for 4.0.0.0 in the directory of the service. It shows me a lot of references in System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityClassGenerator 4.0.0.0 and a bunch more in System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0 in reference caches.

Comment: @JohnPrado: Do you use Entity Framework 4.x? You can still use EF but ver. 1.0 if stuck with .NET 3.5. Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.entityclassgenerator%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I think that the problem was a downgrade from framework 4.0 to 3.5. I'll try to start from scratch to see if it solves the problem. Thanks for the help people.